# Is there a way to disconnect all mutation observers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I am building a chrome extension that listens for new incoming messages in Whatsapp web and filters out the ones that contains certain keywords. I want the clear button to disconnect from all the mutation observers created. Is there a way to do that ?

Here's my popup.js

```
chrome.storage.sync.clear();
const activateBtn = document.querySelector(".activate > button");
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const table = document.querySelector(".table");

const keywordSet = new Set();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");

  if (trs.length === 0) {
    table.style.display = "none";
    activateBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const input = document.querySelector("input");
  const keyword = input.value;
  if (!keyword) return;
  input.value = "";

  table.style.display = "flex";
  activateBtn.style.display = "flex";
  // add new row to tbody
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");

  keywordSet.add(keyword);

  const keywordsRows = [...keywordSet]
    .map(
      (keyword, idx) => `<tr>
  <td>${idx + 1}</td>
  <td>${keyword}</td>
</tr>`
    )
    .join("");

  tbody.innerHTML = keywordsRows;
});

activateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ keywords: [...keywordSet] });
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ isActivated: true });
});

const list = document.querySelector(".list");

setInterval(() => {
  const messages = list.querySelectorAll("li");

  chrome.storage.sync.get("messages", (data) => {
    if (
      !data.messages ||
      data.messages?.length === 0 ||
      messages.length === data.messages?.length
    )
      return;
    const messagesRows = data.messages
      .map(({ message, author }, idx) => `<li>${author}: ${message}</li>`)
      .join("");

    list.innerHTML = messagesRows;
  });
}, 2000);
```

and here is my content.js :

```
(async () => {
  const keywords = (await chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords")).keywords || [];

  const config = { childList: true };

  const contactListContainer = document.querySelector(
    "div.n5hs2j7m.oq31bsqd.gx1rr48f.qh5tioqs"
  );

  const messages = [];

  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    const mutation = mutationList[0];

    if (mutation.target.matches("div.n5hs2j7m.oq31bsqd.gx1rr48f.qh5tioqs")) {
      const latestMessage = mutation.target.lastElementChild;
      const div = latestMessage.querySelector("div.focusable-list-item");

      if (div.classList.contains("message-out")) return;

      const author = latestMessage
        .closest('div[id="main"]')
        .querySelector(
          'span[data-testid="conversation-info-header-chat-title"]'
        ).innerText;

      const newMessage = latestMessage.querySelector(
        "span.selectable-text.copyable-text > span"
      ).innerText;

      // Check if any keyword is present in the newMessage
      const foundKeyword = keywords.some((keyword) =>
        newMessage.includes(keyword)
      );

      if (foundKeyword) {
        messages.push({ author, message: newMessage });
        // remove duplicates from messages, has author and message

        const uniqueValues = {};
        const uniqueMessages = messages.filter((obj) => {
          const key = obj.author + "|" + obj.message;
          if (!uniqueValues[key]) {
            uniqueValues[key] = true;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });

        chrome.storage.sync.set({ messages: uniqueMessages });
      }
    }
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  observer.observe(contactListContainer, config);
})();
```

and here's background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender) => {
  if (!message.isActivated) return;
  else {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: (await getCurrentTab()).id, allFrames: true },
      files: ["/src/js/content.js"],
    });
  }
});

async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  console.log(tab);
  return tab;
}
```

I tried literally everything, I tried creating an array and disconnecting all observers but it didn't work.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will do that. You can put all the observers you create into an array and loop over them, calling `.disconnect()`.

Comment: @Barmar I already did that, but i can't access the observers array from the other js file

Comment: Well then put all observers in a global variable accessible from that other script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you show me how to define a global variable and access it from the other script ?

Comment: 1) `window.foo = []; foo.push(observer)`, 2) `foo.forEach(f => f.disconnect())`